# Dissasembly of lines does not generate assembly instructions

Tags: c

After running my code and stepping thru it, I find that the following two lines are skipped:

```
cCheck_sum = '\0';
cpInternal = &cpData[0];
```

If I go back to my code and disassemble it, I find that the compiler doesn't generate assembly instructions for it.  I know that sometimes the compiler will think that these lines do not affect the preceding code and skips it, but I don't know if this is the case and I need to initialize the variables, so it must step thru it.

I am using FreeScale CodeWarrior compiler IDE 5.9.0

Thank you,
Neil

Comment: Do you actually use the variables after initializing them?

Comment: *I am using FreeScale CodeWarrior compiler IDE 5.9.0* I feel your pain :(. Can you give more context to your question (surrounding code) ? is the code misbehaving in some way ?

Comment: Compiler could be optimizing those steps out. Can you turn down optimization? Also try declaring the variables `volatile`. This should force the compiler to not make any assumptions about the state of the variable.

Comment: Hi jaun.facorro, yes I am, inside a for loop inside that same function.

Comment: Hi cnicutar, not exactly misbehaving, but not giving me the results I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some optimizations that the compiler is doing in your code. This [document](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/user_guide/ETPUTOOLSREF.pdf) indicates (in page 145) that such optimizations do exist for the compiler you are using (if I found the correct reference :P). It also shows how you can disable those optimizations in the IDE or through adding `#pragma`s in your code.

It seems that optimizations can be controlled through *"[...] the **Global Optimizations** settings panel."*

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is free to move code around, split lines into pieces and interleave their execution, and just leave out instructions that do nothing (or whose efect is unnoticeable, i.e, asign a value to a variable, and without using it asigning a new one). If you asign a value, the compiler will assume that value stays until the next asignment, and might use that knowledge to simplify expressions, or even to deduce some branch is never taken. To step though programs compiled with high(er) optimization levels in a debugger can be a bag of fun ;-)